# how do call kotlin fragment from java fragment class

Tags: android, kotlin

This is ActivityUtil code

```
        public class ActivityUtil {

        public static void addFragmentToActivity(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                                                 @NonNull Fragment fragment, int frameId, String fragmentTag) {

            //Fragment fragment1=fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(fragmentManager);
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(fragment);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                transaction.replace(frameId, fragment, fragmentTag);
                transaction.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
                transaction.commit();


        }
        }
```

This is main fragment class here i want add /replace fragment transaction by using kotlin fragment i.e,CameraFragment  Class

I Already used Photofragment class now i want change the kotlin fragment, how do achieve this scenario?

```
    public class ExpLotBcodeFragment extends Fragment{
     public ExpLotBcodeFragment() {      
        }  
          @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setRetainInstance(true);
              }
        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exp_lot_bcode, container, false);


            }


        @OnClick({R.id.scan})
        public void onClick(View view) {
                switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.scan:
                     //here i want to add kotlin call CameraFragment   class

                 //This is old call 
                ActivityUtil.addFragmentToActivity(getFragmentManager(), 
                photoFragment, R.id.frame_content, "photoFragment"); 

                      break;
    }
```

This is kotlin class

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment() {   

  companion object {

    fun newInstance(): CameraFragment {
      return CameraFragment ()
    }
  }


  override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, 
                            container: ViewGroup?, 
                            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_exp_lot_bcode, container, false)
  }

}
```

From CameraFragment class i want to add/replace to ExpLotBcodeFragment class ?

Comment: Not clear about your question

Comment: I have android app with java class name as photofragment and in the same app I have created kotlin fragment  name as camerafragment . I want load the photo fragment instead of camera fragment

Comment: How do the fragment transaction between java fragment and kotlin fragment

Comment: Add both fragment and ActivityUtil code

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you have to call `CameraFragment.Companion.newInstance()` or directly call `new CameraFragment()` to get `instance` of `CameraFragment`.
Check below:

```
@OnClick({R.id.scan})
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.scan:
            CameraFragment cameraFragment = CameraFragment.Companion.newInstance();
            ActivityUtil.addFragmentToActivity(getFragmentManager(),
                    cameraFragment, R.id.frame_content, "cameraFragment");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: My Question  is how to call from ExpLotBcodeFragment (Java ) to CameraFragment (Kotlin)